# How to correctly pass string value to user defined function using python3 argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I have written a short program using the secant method to compute the internal rate of return of various companies cash flows which are defined as callable functions. Each function being named after the companies stock market ticker or epic. The program is run with the following command line parameters:    , and uses argparse to parse the command line parameters.
Example: python3 SecantMethod.py grg 0.2 0.4 6.
When the program runs it produces a ‘str object is not callable’ error, which so far I have been unable to resolve. The problem seems to be related to the way argparse passes the required cash flow epic. Removing all the argparse code and inserting a simple print(SecantMethod(roo 0,1 0.2 6)) statement results in the program returning the correct rate and iteration values.

```
import argparse


def SecantMethod(f, x0, x1, d):

    c = 0
    e = 0.5*pow(10, -d)

    while abs(x1 - x0) > e:
        if f(x1) - f(x0) == 0:
            return 'Division by zero'

        x = x1 - f(x1)*(x1 - x0)/(f(x1) - f(x0))
        x0, x1 = x1, x
        c += 1

    return x, c

def grg(x):

    return -1000\
       +100.00/(1 + x)\
       +210.00/(1 + x)**2\
       +331.00/(1 + x)**3\
       +446.10/(1 + x)**4\
      +1610.51/(1 + x)**5
    # root = 27.97% (x = 0.27967730)

def roo(x):

    return -4000\
       +1200/(1 + x)\
       +1410/(1 + x)**2\
       +1875/(1 + x)**3\
       +1050/(1 + x)**4
    # root = 14.30% (x = 0.14299344)


def main():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description= 'Solves f(x) = 0, using the secant method.')

    parser.add_argument('f', type=str, help='function name')
    parser.add_argument('x0', type=float, help='first interval endpoint')
    parser.add_argument('x1', type=float, help='second interval endpoint')
    parser.add_argument('d', type=int, help='number of decimal places')

    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.x0 == args.x1:
        print('\nInvalid input: x0 and x1 must be distinct values.')
        return
    if args.d < 0:
        print('\nInvalid input: d must be a positive integer.')
        return

    # print('\nRoot & number of iterations: ', SecantMethod(roo, 0.1, 0.2, 8))
    print('\nRoot & number of iterations: ', SecantMethod(args.f, args.x0, args.x1, args.d))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: your method expects a function to be passed to it and your just passing a string from the arg parse. you need to give it a callable function not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string `'grg'` is not the same as the function `grg`.

One way to handle this is to provide a mapping:

```
valid_functions = {
    'grg': grg,
    'roo': roo,
}
# ...
SecantMethod(valid_functions[args.f], ...)
```